# PMD not installed in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I want to integrate PMD plugin to my eclipse.

I went to eclipse marketplace and installed the PMD. When I clicked on windows->preferences, PMD is not displayed.

Did I went anywhere wrong?

My specification:
Eclipse Mars 1 Release 4.5.1
Installed PMD 1.7.0

Please guide me in integrating PMD to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the PMD plugin per project, there are no global settings.

Left click your project and click preferences and then PMD. Then you'll need to enable PMD and add a ruleset xml file. There might be one included with the plugin, but I'm not sure. If not, I suggest you find one online, but they mostly seem to be outdated, so after you've found a basic one, continue to the [PMD site](https://pmd.github.io/) and go to Online docs -> PMD Java -> rulesets index. I didn't link directly, as urls are version specific - the latest, which is also included in the eclipse plugin is 5.4.0 (as of writing). In the docs you'll find a list of all supported checks, which you can then add to the ruleset.

Comment: Re adding a ruleset file for PMD, this one is fairly recent and could serve as a useful starting point: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/resources/rulesets/java/basic.xml